# Pycharm Not seeing something as defined when it is

Tags: python, pycharm

So I am trying to make a multiple-choice test(it is still in beta right now) and Pycharm does not see a variable/string as defined. It works in codeskulptor.org but not Pycharm. I even tried through Terminal on my mac and still no luck. It gives me the same error "File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'a' is not defined". Can someone please help me with this problem? "a is at "\n(a) are small and simple, lacks a nucleus," this would be the answer to the question. The problem is at "Question(question_prompts[0], "a")" I think because that is where it is defined, right?

```
import time

class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer


question_prompts = [
    """prokaryotic cells have what characteristics?\n(a) are small and simple, lacks a nucleus, 
    do not have organells, are a single cell creatures, and have a cell wall.\n\n """
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a")

]

print("Cell Unit Test")
time.sleep(2)
print("10 seconds until test time, take your stuff off your desk")
#time.sleep(10)
print("The test will now commence")
time.sleep(1)


def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        print(question.prompt)
        answer = input("Answer:\n ")
        if answer == question.answer:
            print("Correct!\n")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Wrong! The correct answer is " + question.answer + "\n")

    print("\nEnd of the test.")
    print("You got " + str(score) + " out of " + str(len(questions)) + " questions correct")


run_test(questions)



class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer


question_prompts = [
    """prokaryotic cells have what characteristics?\n(a) are small and simple, lacks a nucleus, 
    do not have organelles, are single-cell creatures, and have a cell wall.\n\n """
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a")

]

print("Cell Unit Test")
time.sleep(2)
print("10 seconds until test time, take your stuff off your desk")
#time.sleep(10)
print("The test will now commence")
time.sleep(1)


def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        print(question.prompt)
        answer = input("Answer:\n ")
        if answer == question.answer:
            print("Correct!\n")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Wrong! The correct answer is " + question.answer + "\n")

    print("\nEnd of the test.")
    print("You got " + str(score) + " out of " + str(len(questions)) + " questions correct")


run_test(questions)'
```

Comment: If nothing else, you appear to have posted the same code twice.  There's also no obvious line 1 that could even have a variable named `a` (though that may be why you are asking).

Comment: I don't see *any* variables named `a`, so it's not clear why you think it would be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Python 3 code, but you're interpreting it using a Python 2 interpreter in Pycharm. You get this error because `input` in Python 2 has "eval-like" behavior, and it's attempting to literally interpret the "a" you enter as a variable to be referenced.

Change the interpreter you're using in Pycharm to a Python 3 interpreter. Alternatively, you could also change `input` to `raw_input`, but judging by the use of `print()`, this is intended to be run in a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: Thank you. Although it is probably worthless because I am an idiot.

Comment: @that_one_dude You would be surprised how common I see a problem along these lines. The two versions of Python being mostly compatible with each other leads to subtle issues like this.

Comment: @that_one_dude If it makes you feel better, someone just had the exact same problem as you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59041146/3000206